# If $G$ is a finite nonsolvable group then $G$ contains a nontrivial subgroup $H$ such that $\left[H,H\right]=H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Show that if $G$ is a finite nonsolvable group then $G$ contains a nontrivial subgroup $H$ such that $\left[H,H\right]=H$.

Comment: I assume that $H$ should be nontrivial, since $1$ holds this property in every group.

Comment: Is $G$ assumed to be *finite*?

Comment: Yes, $G$ be finite

Answer (score 1):

Note that $[H,H]\leqslant H$ for any group $H$.  Thus, by contrapositive, if $G$ contains no non-trivial subgroup $H$ so that $[H,H]=H$, then $[H,H]$ is a proper subgroup of $H$ for each nontrivial subgroup $H$ of $G$.  In particular, every term of the derived series of $G$ is strictly smaller than the previous term, whence the series converges to $1$, so $G$ is solvable.

Comment: why the derived series converges to $1$

Comment: The derived series is defined by $G^{(0)}=G$ and $G^{(k)}=[G^{(k-1)},G^{(k-1)}]$.  Since we've assumed that $[G^{(k-1)},G^{(k-1)}]$ is strictly smaller than $G^{(k-1)}$, every term decreases in size.  Since $G$ is finite, eventually this must reach the identity.

Comment: Oh. I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $\,G\,$ is simple (and non-abelian, of course) the claim is trivial (why?), so we can assume $\,G\,$ has a non-trivial normal subgroup. Now take a peek at a non-trivial normal *minimal* subgroup.